# Issues with Jasmine's spyOn toHaveBeenCalled method

Tags: javascript, tdd, jasmine

Can anyone possibly tell me why the following test fails.

```
var Person = function() {};

Person.prototype.helloSomeone = function(toGreet) {
  return this.sayHello() + " " + toGreet;
};

Person.prototype.sayHello = function() {
  return "Hello";
};

describe("Person", function() {
 it("calls the sayHello() function", function() {
   var fakePerson = new Person();
   spyOn(fakePerson, "sayHello");
   fakePerson.helloSomeone("world");
   expect(fakePerson.sayHello).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I took it from [here](http://evanhahn.com/?p=181) and he said it works. I can see the spyOn method is creating a wrapper function of the same name on the person object i.e. fakePerson.sayHello is being invoked on the object and not the prototype.

Many thanks

Comment: The tests fail because I'm also using jasmine-sinon.js. Not sure why yet but the test work as soon as I remove it.

Comment: Hi screenm0nkey, you might be interested why I think that using `toHaveBeenCalled` isn't the best choice in this use-case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16851650/705888

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tests failed because I was also using jasmine-sinon.js.

Comment: Thank you for updating this, I kept looking at what I was doing wrong with spy, as soon as I switched over to the sinon syntax it worked. I didn't realize this project was using sinon.

Comment: Shouldn't this code work as regular jasmine syntax with or without sinon?

Answer (score 4):

One possible problem with your test cases is that you haven't specified that the original method should be called. What would have a proper behavior is the following (note the "andCallThrough") :

```
describe("Person", function() {
 it("calls the sayHello() function", function() {
   var fakePerson = new Person();
   spyOn(fakePerson, "sayHello").andCallThrough();
   fakePerson.helloSomeone("world");
   expect(fakePerson.sayHello).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

You can see the documentation page of Jasmine for more information about the other possibility : https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Spies

Edit: A quick look at the [jasmine-sinon documentation](https://github.com/froots/jasmine-sinon) brings up the following:

> > **<strike>Warning</strike>**
> >
> > <strike>jasmine-sinon currently overwrites any Jasmine matchers of the same name used for its own  spying features. I plan to allow these to be optionally retained in the future.</strike>
> >
> > <strike>The native Jasmine matchers that are overwritten are:</strike>
> >
> > - <strike>toHaveBeenCalled()</strike>
> > - <strike>toHaveBeenCalledWith()</strike>

<strike>If you want to use jasmine-sinon, you have to use their API and not the one of Jasmine.</strike>

**Edit**: As of [Feb 2012](https://github.com/froots/jasmine-sinon/commit/0da0de94a10a084335b0359cbedb4f602e0843c5):

> You can also use Jasmine spies alongside your Sinon spies.
>   jasmine-sinon will detect which you're using and use the appropriate matcher.

Comment: @screenm0nkey Can you be in that case a bit more specific about what you are expecting and exactly what error you are getting when the test fails.

Comment: Well, I would expect the test to pass because it should. The spy is not working properly as I copied the example from https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Spies and it also failed. I guess there is something wrong with my setup.

Comment: Hey HoLyVieR. See my comment below the original post. it's something to do with jasmine-sinon.js.

Comment: +1 for andCallThrough() (http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/jsdoc/symbols/jasmine.Spy.html#andCallThrough)