# Trying to understand Jasmine's toHaveBeenCalled() matcher

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, bdd, jasmine

I am new to `jasmine` here is my `src` file in which i create `Auth` class

```
function Auth() {
}

Auth.prototype.isEmpty = function(str) {
    return (!str || 0 === str.length);
}

Auth.prototype.Login = function (username , password) {
    if (this.isEmpty(username) || this.isEmpty(password)) {
        return "Username or Password cann't be blank ";
    }
    else {
        return "Logged In !";
    }
}
```

now i want to test jasmine's `toHaveBeenCalled()` matcher . Here is what i write

```
it("should be able to Login", function () {
    spyOn(authobj);
    expect(authobj.Login('abc', 'abc')).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

but it says that `undefined() method does not exist`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

EDIT: Look at [basecode answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16851650/57095) for a better approach

---

[From the docs](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/#section-Spies), you should use it like the following:

```
spyOn(foo, 'setBar');

it("tracks that the spy was called", function() {
  expect(foo.setBar).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

So you should write:

```
it("should be able to Login", function () {
  spyOn(authobj, 'isEmpty');  
  authobj.Login('abc', 'abc');  
  expect(authobj.isEmpty).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: after trying what you said it gives me this `Error: Expected a spy, but got undefined. in http://localhost:57494/Scripts/Jasmine/jasmine.js (line 1361)`

Comment: Oops my bad, I can't try that right now, but see my updated answer.

Comment: I want to know that When i call `Login` fucntion , then does it call `isEmpty` function or not ? .

Comment: Then you should place the spy on `isEmpty` an call `Login` I update my answer.

Comment: Downvoted this answer because it advocates spying on implementation details. See the answer from @basecode for a better approach.

Comment: @jessegavin thanks for pointing this out, I will check basecode answer and see where I can improve.

Answer (score 27):

Looking at your use-case, I can't recommend using `toHaveBeenCalled` here. `toHaveBeenCalled` is useful in cases where you want test callbacks (async) or in combination with mocks.

Consider everything that happens within `Auth.prototype.Login` as implementation detail which is not visible to the "outerworld". You shouldn't test implementation details. Which triggers  two questions.

#### Why shouldn't I test implementation details?

It makes refactoring hard. Let's say you want to replace `Auth.prototype.isEmpty` for some reasons by `underscore.isEmpty`. Some days later you decide to replace `underscore` completely by `lodash`. This would force you to change your test three times. Consider everything that prevents you from refactoring easily as a "no-go".

#### What shall I test instead?

Public API. Everything that is visible to the "outerworld". Which is in your case "Logged In !" and "Username or Password cann't be blank ".

Which results in 3 tests:

```
describe('Login', function() {

 it('returns "success" string when username and password are not empty', function() {
   expect(new Auth().Login('non-empty', 'non-empty')).toBe('Logged In !');
 });

 it('returns "failure" string when username is empty', function() {
   expect(new Auth().Login('', 'non-empty')).toBe('Username or Password cannot be blank');
 });

 it('returns "failure" string when password is empty', function() {
   expect(new Auth().Login('non-empty', '')).toBe('Username or Password cannot be blank');
 });

});
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Thanks for taking the time to explain the right way to test.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple to use, basically:-

```
spyOn(<name_of_the_object>, '<name_of_the_method>')

expect(<name_of_the_object>.<name_of_the_method>).toHaveBeenCalled();
```